# Apache - Reverse proxy

Tags: redirects, apache2, httpd.conf

I am using Apache 2 and using the below virtual host definition in httpd.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName localhost   
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/stackoverflow/ 
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/stackoverflow/ 
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule  ^(market|stock|mutual)$ stackoverflow/$1 [L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Here, when I type

```
localhost/market
```

then Apache internally rewrite the URL and show me the contents of

```
localhost:8080/stackoverflow/market
```

Now my problem is: When I click on any of the link of that site having following URL

```
localhost:8080/stackoverflow/market/abc
```

Then, My address bar will show the above URL

I want my Apache server to redirect me to

```
localhost/market/abc
```

means User will be shown the above URL, but the contents will come from

```
localhost:8080/stackoverflow/market/abc
```

I was thinking if I need to set reverse proxy for this. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

This is what a proper reverse proxy should look like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName sub.domain.org
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyVia full
        ProxyPass / http://10.160.1.234:80/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://10.160.1.234:80/
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_name.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_name.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

But it is REALLY unclear what you are doing. Do you WANT it to rewrite to port 8080? Are you just trying to rewrite the URL (remove one subdirectory)? If so, then you can stick with standard rewrite rules rather than a reverse proxy.